# How can I link multiple email address to one user in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Our organization has users making commits from home or 'out of the office' frequently. I've noticed a lot of commits from personal email addresses (most likely when the users are working on their own device).

[image: Personal email commit]

[image: Organizational email commit]

These two commits are from the same person, only using a different email address likely because they're committing from a different pc with different global git config. I'd like to link both of these email addresses to the same user account similiar to what GitHub allows (you must have an account to reach this account settings link):

https://github.com/settings/emails

How can I do this in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you should commit a `.mailmap` file to map different mails to one.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors or https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Using-.mailmap

PS:

> These two commits are from the same person, only using a different email address likely because they're committing from a different pc with different global git config.

Perhaps these persons should not forgot to change settings for one repository
or even better, use [conditional include](https://pliutau.com/using-different-git-emails/)

Comment: Perhaps, but, in a perfect world we can have multiple email addresses and not worry about the consequences as much  :) ... Ideally there would be a way to retrospectively apply this identity. I really like how github handles it

Comment: @KyleBurkett I think that `.mailmap` file works retrospectively. Thank you. That's only the 2nd thanks in all these years :( It's not a perfect tool but it could really. That's just a shame that I don't have time and want to maintain it (I don't use it anymore since years) and that no one get involved...so their is no active maintainer anymore :( But I'm happy it is useful for someone (I used to just see issues and people reporting problems on github project...)

Comment: I used the .mailmap today and found it is retrospective and it solves the problem perfectly. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Is there a delay after pushing before the .mailmap take effect in the web ui or have done something wrong? It seemed to take effect immediately in `git log`.